# how to use socket.setSoTimeout()?

Tags: java, sockets

When you set a timeout on a socket with `socket.seSoTimeout(5000);` does the socket close or just stop listening after it times out? Will I have to open the socket again to continue listening or will it open automatically?

```
receivingSocket.setSoTimeout(5000); // set timer
try{
  receivingSocket.receive(packet);
}
catch(SocketTimeoutException e){
  System.out.println("### Timed out after 5 seconds.");
}
//will I have to reopen the socket here?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test your question by wrapping your try/catch in a `while (true)`.  The short answer is no, you do not have to reopen the socket.  The `setSoTimeout()` is just telling the socket to wait this long for data before you try to do anything else.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
DatagramSocket receiveSocket = new DatagramSocket(5505, InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"));
receiveSocket.setSoTimeout(5000);
while (true) {
    try {
        receiveSocket.receive(p);
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException ste) {
        System.out.println("### Timed out after 5 seconds");
    }
}
```

Results (You can see that the socket is still reusable after it timesout):

[image]

Comment: Okay, wow thank you. Didn't realize it was that simple. I guess I was over thinking it. Essentially it's waiting for 'recieveSocket.receive(p);' to actually get a packet. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSoTimeout-int-) states:

> If the timeout expires, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, **though the ServerSocket is still valid**

So no, it will not close the socket. Next time you're wondering how something works, check out the documentation

Comment: That's the wrong Javdoc. The question isn't about `ServerSockets`.